# repeat git pull without password after remving changes to tracked files

Tags: git

Many times when I do `git pull`, it downloads all changes from the server and then gives me an error `Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:`. So, I either stash or remove changes in the listed files. Then I have to do `git pull` again by entering username and password. Since git would've downloaded the changes from server in my first attempt, is it possible to reuse that directly using some command? I don't want to enter username and password again.

PS: This is not about storing my password in a git cache file or such. I am okay with entering the password the first time. But I want to skip entering it again the second time, if I got some error the first time.

Comment: I've never had this problem - it sounds like your git config is messed-up.

Comment: So, after removing changes, what command would you execute?

Comment: I'd do a reinstall of git, and install GitKraken.

Comment: I don't think you're getting my point. Suppose you do `git pull` and you get the error I mentioned. Then the obvious solution is to remove the listed changes. After removing the changes, what command would you execute?

Comment: `git pull` includes `git fetch` - so the new commits are already in your `.git` database. `git pull` would just be doing a fast-forward. Instead, make a new branch and then decide if you want to merge or rebase.

Comment: Cool. Is there any other command to just fast-forward what's already there in `.git` database other than `git pull` or `git fetch`?

Comment: @Dai if all you want to do is to see just run `gitk --all` in your git console, that one is free :P

Comment: @Dai both are tools. In my opinion a tool which already is installed on the pc is more useful than one which is not. Just like I wouldn't buy an IPhone to make a single call I wouldn't download a program to get a graph unless necessary :P... which one is best and why can probably be discussed too :P

Comment: @Dai: please don't insist on OP using an entirely different tool when he asks a perfectly reasonable question about a specific tool. sure, GitKraken might be better for some, but apart from maybe suggesting it once, it has no place in this question.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I recommended it specifically because it’s perfect for helping people get to grips with how git works - and for getting people out of sticky situations. I wasn’t partaking in any kind of tooling bigotry. Axosoft isn’t paying me to say that either. It’s an indictment against the designers of gitk than anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git pull` is actually running 2 commands. (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

1. A git fetch to get the changes from the server.
2. A git merge (or rebase) up against the remote.

So what you want to do is rerun the second step.

`git merge @{u}`

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @NagabhushanSN Good to hear ^^